# avoiding to use temp strings with .c_str command?

Tags: substr, c-str

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid using a temporary string in this case:

```
tempString = inputString.substr(commaLast,commaCurrent-1);
yPos = strtod(tempString.c_str(), NULL);
```

There is no way to use the substr command and returning a c_str without first storing the substring in a temp string (supposing I dont want to modify the original string).

Comment: Are you doing anything else with inputString?   The fact that you're using strtod and c_str in the first place suggests to me that you might get a better solution using a std::stringstream instead.

Comment: yes, I'm splitting the string based on several conditions. I'm trying to parse a SVG line. I've looked at std::stringsteam, but I thought this was only good for whitespace splitting

Comment: the >> operator is whitespace delimited by default, but you don't have to let that stop you;  a stringstream will let you handle string data in the same way as input from std::cin, so before/after a read, you can skip over subsequent characters using `istream::ignore( /* ... */ )` up to and including any delimiter of your choosing.  (I don't know much about the the SVG format, so that may or may not be useful to you - but I find it works fine for simple delimited data)

Comment: intere-string! thanks for that. Unfortunately for the SVG format sometimes I need to read the delimiter too. For example coordinates can be `1,2,-3,-4,5` or `1,2-3-4,5` for "efficiency". So I actually need to read the delimiter `-` sometimes as a value too (and not skip it). I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
yPos = strtod(inputString.substr(commaLast,commaCurrent-1).c_str(), NULL);
```

Comment: Arg! I could have sworn that I did! I guess I was trying:
    yPos = strtod(inputString.c_str().substr(commaLast, commaCurrent-1), NULL);